# Nested callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, callback, nested

In my program, I have declared an object myObject like this :

```
function myObject()
{
  this.start=start; 
  function start(callbackFunction)
  {
    // Do something with callbackFunction
   }
}
```

In my main() method, I create objects and I want to start nested callback like this :

```
var myObject1 = new myObject();
var myObject2 = new myObject();

var list = [];
list.push(myObject1);
list.push(myObject2);      

var result = function() {};
var obj;
for (var i=list.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
  obj = list[i];        
  result = function() { obj.start(result);}
}  
result();  // I want to do myObject1.start(myObject2.start)); e.g. a nested callback
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

How can I correct my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result variable is redefined after each iteration.

Your need to set your function like so :

```
var myObject1 = new myObject();
var myObject2 = new myObject();

var list = [];
list.push(myObject1);
list.push(myObject2);      

var result= function() {};
for (var i=list.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    var obj = list[i];
    result = obj.start.bind(obj, result);
}  
result();
```

Using the bind method will force the state of the variable to be saved at each iteration.

Comment: You are right about the problem, but the solution doesn't work. The original code used functions with no parameters as callbacks, you use functions with 1 parameter. If myObject uses the callback as `callback()`, then the first call will be ok (it will be  `function(){}()`), but the second call will not be ok (it will be `undefined()`).

Comment: Yes ! That's perfect !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using closures properly.

In your for loop you declare a function that uses a variable from the outer scope (result). When the for loop ends, the result variable will contain the last function defined, instead of the one defined at step i, as you would expect.

One solution as you so very well hinted in a comment is recursivity:

```
function myObject(name)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.start= function(callbackFunction) {
    console.log(this.name);
    // Do something with callbackFunction
    callbackFunction();
   };
}

var myObject1 = new myObject(1);
var myObject2 = new myObject(2);

var list = [];
list.push(myObject1);
list.push(myObject2);      

var runner = function(list, currentIndex) { // recursive function
  if (currentIndex < 0) return function(){ console.log('INITIAL');};
  return function(){ 
    list[currentIndex].start(runner(list, currentIndex-1));
  };
};

runner(list, list.length-1)();
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ukeBUweG/2/edit

One last note, the solution above tries to stay true to your initial code. It is not

```
obj1.start(obj2.start(function(){}))
```

, but

```
function(){ obj1.start(function(){ obj2.start(function(){}) })}();
```